# Как отключить масштабирование через Ctrl+колёсико мыши у FlowDocumentScrollViewer в WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

Как отключить масштабирование через Ctrl+колёсико мыши у FlowDocumentScrollViewer в WPF?

Comment: Перехватить Preview-событие и сказать `e.Handled = true`

Comment: Я попытался найти сам. Не вышло. Забросил эту тему на  несколько дней, теперь решил вернуться. Не подскажите ли как называется это Preview-событие?

Comment: [PreviewMouseWheel](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.uielement.previewmousewheel) наверное